# How to install numpy link against with intel MKL in IBM power8(ppc64le) machine?

Tags: numpy, intel-mkl

I know intel has already written a document for numpy build with mkl. but my machine CPU is power8(IBM) (OS: centos), I download in this link: https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/products/postregistration/?sn=3VGW-J93Z886P&EmailID=mac16%40tsinghua.edu.cn&Sequence=2115993&dnld=t

but when I run install.sh

```
[root@power8 intel_mkl]# sh install.sh 
install.sh: line 50: [: -lt: unary operator expected
install.sh: line 53: [: -eq: unary operator expected
The IA-32 architecture host installation is no longer supported.
The product cannot be installed on this system.
Please refer to product documentation for more information.
```

Does intel mkl support power8 machine? and how to build numpy link against mkl in power8 machine exactly?

Comment: [MKL is Intel-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) - so this is a non-starter - you'll need to write equivalent routines to replace whichever MKL calls are being used.

Comment: @PaulR What do you mean? Do you mean My IBM power 8 machine cannot install intel MKL with numpy?

Comment: @PaulR I found a performance benchmark which tells that power8 can install intel MKL: http://excel.fit.vutbr.cz/submissions/2016/056/56.pdf

Comment: The paper you linked to is benchmarking POWER8 versus Intel Haswell. It talks about a benchmark which uses BLAS, which most likely uses MKL on an Intel platform, and something else on non-Intel platforms.